# how to convert json format table to excel?

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

[image]I have an input in json format which contains table information. Now I want to extract the information from {tables--> rows --> content-->"DESCRIPTION"}. How to extract the content from each?

> input.json

```
{"tables": [
    {
        "bbox": [
            186,
            858,
            1158,
            1218
        ],
        "column_types": [
            "table_column_description",
            "table_column_other",
            "table_column_quantity",
            "table_column_quantity",
            "table_column_quantity",
            "table_column_quantity",
            "table_column_rate",
            "table_column_amount_total"
        ],
        "page": 0,
        "rows": [
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            858,
                            408,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "DESCRIPTION",
                        "value": "DESCRIPTION",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            858,
                            480,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "M4A\nCode",
                        "value": "M4A\nCode",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            858,
                            648,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "AMOUNT\n(RM)",
                        "value": "AMOUNT\n(RM)",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            858,
                            750,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "DISCOUNT\n0RM)",
                        "value": "DISCOUNT\n0RM)",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            858,
                            870,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "GROSS AMOUNT\n(RM)",
                        "value": "GROSS AMOUNT\n(RM)",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            858,
                            954,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "GST\n(RM)",
                        "value": "GST\n(RM)",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            858,
                            1008,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "TAX\nCODE",
                        "value": "TAX\nCODE",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            858,
                            1158,
                            918
                        ],
                        "content": "PAYABLE\n(PRM)",
                        "value": "PAYABLE\n(PRM)",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "header"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            972,
                            408,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "EKOOI -CONSULTATION",
                        "value": "EKOOI -CONSULTATION",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            972,
                            480,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "",
                        "value": "",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            972,
                            648,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "90.00",
                        "value": "90.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            972,
                            750,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "0.00",
                        "value": "0.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            972,
                            870,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "90.00",
                        "value": "90.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            972,
                            954,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "5.40",
                        "value": "5.40",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            972,
                            1008,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "SR",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            972,
                            1158,
                            1008
                        ],
                        "content": "95.40",
                        "value": "95.40",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            1008,
                            408,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "EKOOI - PROCEDURE FEE",
                        "value": "EKOOI - PROCEDURE FEE",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            1008,
                            480,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "",
                        "value": "",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            1008,
                            648,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "260.00",
                        "value": "260.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            1008,
                            750,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "(26.00)",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            1008,
                            870,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "234.00",
                        "value": "234.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            1008,
                            954,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "14.04",
                        "value": "14.04",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            1008,
                            1008,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "SR",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            1008,
                            1158,
                            1044
                        ],
                        "content": "248.04",
                        "value": "248.04",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            1038,
                            408,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "EKOOI -TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value": "EKOOI -TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            1038,
                            480,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "",
                        "value": "",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            1038,
                            648,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "125.00",
                        "value": "125.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            1038,
                            750,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "0.00",
                        "value": "0.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            1038,
                            870,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "125.00",
                        "value": "125.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            1038,
                            954,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "7.50",
                        "value": "7.50",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            1038,
                            1008,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "SR",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            1038,
                            1158,
                            1068
                        ],
                        "content": "132.50",
                        "value": "132.50",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            1062,
                            408,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "COLONOSCOPY PLUS/MINUS\nIBCOPIO/DESTRUCTION OF\nLKSOON- TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value": "COLONOSCOPY PLUS/MINUS IBCOPIO/DESTRUCTION OF LKSOON- TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            1062,
                            480,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "H2000",
                        "value": "H2000",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            1062,
                            648,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "1,125.00\n125.00\n--o.",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            1062,
                            750,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "(112.50)\n0.00\n-.--",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            1062,
                            870,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "1,012.50\n125.00\n-----",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            1062,
                            954,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "60.75\n7.50\n.--",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            1062,
                            1008,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "5R\n-",
                        "value": "5",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            1062,
                            1158,
                            1170
                        ],
                        "content": "1,073.25\n132.50\n---.0-",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            1158,
                            408,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "OGDS MITH BIOPSY",
                        "value": "OGDS MITH BIOPSY",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            1158,
                            480,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "G6500",
                        "value": "G6500",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            1158,
                            648,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "405.00",
                        "value": "405.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            1158,
                            750,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "40.50)\nT0.2v",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            1158,
                            870,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "364.50",
                        "value": "364.50",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            1158,
                            954,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "21.87",
                        "value": "21.87",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            1158,
                            1008,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "SR",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            1158,
                            1158,
                            1194
                        ],
                        "content": "386.37",
                        "value": "386.37",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            186,
                            1182,
                            408,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "EKOOI - TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value": "EKOOI - TREATMENT FEE",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            414,
                            1182,
                            480,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "",
                        "value": "",
                        "value_type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            558,
                            1182,
                            648,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "125.00",
                        "value": "125.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            648,
                            1182,
                            750,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "0.00",
                        "value": "0.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            744,
                            1182,
                            870,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "125.00",
                        "value": "125.00",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            876,
                            1182,
                            954,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "7.50",
                        "value": "7.50",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            954,
                            1182,
                            1008,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "SR",
                        "value": null,
                        "value_type": null
                    },
                    {
                        "bbox": [
                            1068,
                            1182,
                            1158,
                            1218
                        ],
                        "content": "132.50",
                        "value": "132.50",
                        "value_type": "number"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "data"
            }
        ]
    }
]`
```

> Expected Output in --> Excel or csv

DESCRIPTION  M4A\nCode AMOUNT\n(RM) DISCOUNT\n0RM) GROSS AMOUNT\n(RM)
  EKOOI -CONSULTATION     90.00

```
import json

f = open('input_json_file.json')
data = json.load(f)

print(data['tables'][0]["rows"][0]["cells"][0]["content"])
print(data['tables'][0]["rows"][0]["cells"][1]["content"])
```

Comment: Can you put a sample output for couple of rows with the input given by you?

Comment: i want the output in excel like in the picture

Comment: If you are familiar with pandas, there are functions to [read json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) files.

Comment: i am new new to python .please guide me with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to extract some fields from your json file, and convert that to a csv file. But as some of your fields contain special characters (`\n`), I strongly advise you to use the csv module to write the csv file.

Code can be as simple as:

```
import json
import csv

with open('input.json') as jsonfile, open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8',
                                          'newline'='') as csvfile:
    js = json.load(jsonfile)
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for table in js['tables']:
        for row in table['rows']:
            wr.writerow([cell['content'] for cell in row['cells']])
```

If your localized version of Excel uses a delimiter other than the comma (`,`), for example a semicolon (`;`) you just have to declare if to the `csv.writer`:

```
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: thank you so much i got the output really i m very happy

Answer (score 1):

Any well formed JSON can be imported into excel cells using menu options.
(VBA can be used but is not essential).
Use the Data tab to open a query to the file where the JSON is stored.
The power query editor window should open with names and values imported.
JSON formatted values are normally displayed as a cell containing the word 'Record'. Convert by either using the context menu as required, or drill-down using the expand icon to convert into columns.
Select Close & Load to open the converted data into a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts the json to CSV.

```
import json
import sys
import os
from collections import OrderedDict                


def createOp(ipJsonFile, opCsvFile):
    jsonData = None;
    with open(ipJsonFile) as jFH:
        jsonData = json.load(jFH, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

    oFH = open(opCsvFile,"w");


    for row in jsonData["tables"][0]["rows"]:
        #print "id:",id, row;
        line = "";
        for col in row["cells"]:
            #print col["value"];
            val = col["value"];
            if val != None:
                val = val.replace("\n","-");
            line += str(val) + ",";
        #print line;
        oFH.write(line + "\n")
    oFH.close();        

def main(args):
    createOp(args[1], args[2]);


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "json_to_csv.py <ip json file> <op csv file>";
        sys.exit(-1);
    main(sys.argv)
```

Run this code like this

```
python json_to_csv.py <ip json> <op csv file>
```

I changed the code(just 1 line) to run it on Python3

```
import json
import sys
import os
from collections import OrderedDict


def createOp(ipJsonFile, opCsvFile):
    jsonData = None;
    with open(ipJsonFile) as jFH:
        jsonData = json.load(jFH, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

    oFH = open(opCsvFile,"w");


    for row in jsonData["tables"][0]["rows"]:
        #print "id:",id, row;
        line = "";
        for col in row["cells"]:
            #print col["value"];
            val = col["value"];
            if val != None:
                val = val.replace("\n","-");
            line += str(val) + ",";
        #print line;
        oFH.write(line + "\n")
    oFH.close();

def main(args):
    createOp(args[1], args[2]);


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("json_to_csv.py <ip json file> <op csv file>");
        sys.exit(-1);
    main(sys.argv)
```

And it works properly.

Comment: thanks a lot but i m getting a delimiter error while running this code

Comment: i m running on python 3

Comment: I think you need to change the print statements in my code and i am not so well versed in Python 3.

Comment: currently i m using the above code to get output please check now only i added that code

Comment: I ran the code with python3 and it works fine. I have added that code(Edited my answer)